# How to select rows and columns that meet criteria from a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, slice

Let's say I've got a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Item ID":["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"], "Value1":[1, 2, 3, 4, 0], 
        "Value2":[4, 5, 1, 8, 7], "Value3":[3, 8, 1, 2, 0],"Value4":[4, 5, 7, 9, 4]})
print(df1)
        Item_ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
0             A       1       4       3       4
1             B       2       5       8       5
2             C       3       1       1       7
3             D       4       8       2       9
4             E       0       7       0       4
```

Now I've got a second dataframe that looks like:

```
df2 = {"Item ID":["A", "C", "D"], "Value5":[4, 5, 7]}
print(df2)

     Item_ID  Value5
0          A       4
1          C       5
2          D       7
```

What I want do is find where the Item ID's match between my two data frames, and then add the "Value5" column values to the intersection of the rows AND ONLY columns Value1 and Value2 from df1 (these columns could change every iteration, so these columns need to be contained in a variable).

My output should show:

- 4 added to Row A, columns "Value1" and "Value2"
- 5 added to Row C, columns "Value1" and "Value2"
- 7 added to Row D, columns "Value1" and "Value2"

  ```
          Item_ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
  0             A       5       8       3       4
  1             B       2       5       8       5
  2             C       8       6       1       7
  3             D       11     15       2       9
  4             E       0       7       0       4
  ```

Of course my data is many thousand rows long.   I can do it using a for loop, but this is taking way too long.  I want to be able to vectorize this in some way.  Any ideas?

---

This is what I ended up doing based on @sammywemmy's suggestions

```
#Takes columns names and changes them into a list
names = df1.colnames.tolist()

#Merge df1 and df2 based on 'Item_ID'
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Item_ID', how='outer')

for i in range(len(names)):

    #using assign and **, we can bring in variable names with assign.  
    #Then add our Value 5 column
    merged = merged.assign(**{names[i] : lambda x : x[names[i]] + x.Value5})

#Only keep all the columns before and including 'Value4'
df1= merged.loc[:,:'Value4']
```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output as well

Comment: i probably am wrong - item -id matches on A, so value 1 is 5 and value 2 should be 8 not 9; item_id C looks fine; what happened to E? why is the sum on E and not D?

Comment: sorry still clarifying the question...

Comment: ok. when u r done then. value 2 for item_ID 'A' should be 8, not 9 though. unless there's a different logic

Comment: Yes you are correct, thanks for the catch, should be a complete question now.

Comment: @OrangeMan welcome to SO. +1 for providing a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 #set 'Item ID' as the index
 df1 = df1.set_index('Item ID')
 df2 = df2.set_index('Item ID')

 #create list of columns that you are interested in
 list_of_cols = ['Value1','Value2']

 #create two separate dataframes
 #unselected will not contain the columns you want to add
 unselected = df1.drop(list_of_cols,axis=1)

 #this will contain the columns you wish to add
 selected = df1.filter(list_of_cols)

 #reindex df2 so it has the same indices as df1
 #then convert to a series
 #fill the null values with 0
 A = df2.reindex(index=selected.index,fill_value=0).loc[:,'Value5']

 #add the series A to selected
 selected = selected.add(A,axis='index')

 #combine selected and unselected into one dataframe
 result = pd.concat([unselected,selected],axis=1)

 #this part is extra to get ur dataframe back to the way it was
 #assumption here is that it is value1, value 2, bla bla
 #so 1>2>3
 #if ur columns are not actually Value1, Value2, 
 #bla bla, then a different sorting has to be used
 #alternatively before the calculations, 
 #you could create a mapping of the columns to numbers
 #that will give u a sorting mechanism and 
 #restore ur dataframe after calculations are complete
columns = sorted(result.columns,key = lambda x : x[-1])

 #reindex back to the way it was 
 result = result.reindex(columns,axis='columns')

 print(result)

           Value1   Value2  Value3  Value4
Item ID             
A              5       8       3      4
B              2       5       8      5
C              8       6       1      7
D              11      15      2      9
E              0       7       0      4
```

Alternative solution, using python's built-in dictionaries:

```
#create dictionaries
dict1 = (df1
         #create temporary column
         #and set as index
         .assign(temp=df1['Item ID'])
         .set_index('temp')
         .to_dict('index')
         )

dict2 =  (df2
         .assign(temp=df2['Item ID'])
         .set_index('temp')
         .to_dict('index')
         )

list_of_cols = ['Value1','Value2']

intersected_keys = dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()

key_value_pair = [(key,col) for key in intersected_keys
                 for col in list_of_cols ]

#check for keys that are in both dict1 and 2
#loop through dict 1 and add values from dict2
#can be optimized with a dict comprehension
#leaving as is for better clarity IMHO

for key, val in key_value_pair:
    dict1[key][val] = dict1[key][val] + dict2[key]['Value5']

#print(dict1)

    {'A': {'Item ID': 'A', 'Value1': 5, 'Value2': 8, 'Value3': 3, 'Value4': 4},
  'B': {'Item ID': 'B', 'Value1': 2, 'Value2': 5, 'Value3': 8, 'Value4': 5},
 'C': {'Item ID': 'C', 'Value1': 8, 'Value2': 6, 'Value3': 1, 'Value4': 7},
 'D': {'Item ID': 'D', 'Value1': 11, 'Value2': 15, 'Value3': 2, 'Value4': 9},
 'E': {'Item ID': 'E', 'Value1': 0, 'Value2': 7, 'Value3': 0, 'Value4': 4}}

#create dataframe
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1,orient='index').reset_index(drop=True)

    Item ID Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
 0     A       5       8       3       4
 1     B       2       5       8       5
 2     C       8       6       1       7
 3     D       11      15      2       9
 4     E       0       7       0       4
```

Comment: I'm no expert in python but I hope someone can post a pythonic solution which involves logic only, something like usage of lists/dictionaries

Comment: didnt quite get that. u dont want the solution in pandas?

Comment: pandas is fine by me, btw, I'm not the OP, I happened to see this interesting Q. My point is, you can enrich the answer by providing an alternate native solution which involves using fundamental python structures as mentioned above.

Comment: oh. not a bad idea. i'll give it a shot. probably jump out of pandas into dicts/lists as suggested

Comment: @sammywemmy - this works for when we have only 2 columns that we need to modify.  But what if I need to modify a list of columns all at once that changes every iteration?  Let's says the list contains "Value1" ad "Value2".  Again you could image I want to apply this to many columns.  Clarified the question.

Comment: morning @OrangeMan. made changes to the code. Included a list containing ur relevant columns. u can add or remove from the list. lemme know how it goes

Comment: @sammywemmy I was able to do enough searching on the web that I made your original solution work with some modifications.  I posted that solution in my original questions.  So how does this work?   Do I say your answer is the answer?